# TweetSharp Library issues

Tags: twitter, tweetsharp

I've this code which is not working.
If i try to post in twitter with the generated access token and access token secret from the page, it works perfectly, but if i try to retrieve the access tokens it doesn't work, it goes to the page, i authorize the app and it doesn't retrieve the tokens, can anyone help me please?

```
var oauth_consumer_key = "******************************";
var oauth_consumer_secret = "**************************************";
var service = new TwitterService(oauth_consumer_key, oauth_consumer_secret);

OAuthRequestToken requestToken = service.GetRequestToken();
string authUrl = service.GetAuthorizationUri(requestToken).ToString();
Process.Start(authUrl);
```

TILL THIS POINT THE CODE IS WORKING.

START OF NOT WORKING CODE

```
OAuthAccessToken accessToken = service.GetAccessToken(requestToken);
string token = accessToken.Token.ToString(); 
string tokenSecret = accessToken.TokenSecret.ToString(); 
Console.WriteLine(accessToken.Token);
Console.WriteLine(accessToken.TokenSecret);
Console.ReadKey();
service.AuthenticateWith(accessToken.Token,accessToken.TokenSecret);
```

This part is working if i authenticate directly with the strings generated in the app page

```
//service.AuthenticateWith("*****************************", "***********************************");
service.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions
                {
                    Status = "yayayayayayayayayayyayayay"
                });
```

I really dont understand why it doesn't work, can someone please help me? 
Thank you so much guys

Comment: Do you get an unauthorised response or some other kind of error? Do the token values returned by GetAccessToken look valid/correct? Do they contain any % style encodings that perhaps need to be decoded?

Comment: Thanks for the post, i solved the roblem using tweetinvi library which work very well, i think tweetsharpis outdated now. thank you man